# PHP random file display

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the same script from the link given below to display the files in the directory.

[Link list based on directory without file extension and hyphens in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138046/link-list-based-on-directory-without-file-extension-and-hyphens-in-php)

```
$directory = 'folder/';
$blacklist = array(
   'index'
);

foreach (glob($directory . "*.php") as $file) {
   $parts = pathinfo($file);
   if (!in_array($parts['filename'], $blacklist)) {
      $name = preg_replace("/-/", "", $parts['filename']);
      echo "<li><a href=\"{$file}\">{$name}</a></li>";
   }
}
```

The above script displays all the files (except index.php) in a folder. But I just want to display five random files. Is this possible?

http://s30.postimg.org/hbb1ce67l/screen.jpg

Comment: Please, show some code

Comment: Here you can find the code to list the files Randomly. http://sysaxiom.com/php/order_results.php

Comment: Are you trying to create links to a specific 5 random files, or any 5 random files in the directory?

Comment: @TajMorton Any 5 random files, but i dont want index.php to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your edit, I think this is what you're trying to do?

```
<?php
    // Get all files ending in .php in the directory
    $rand_files = glob("*.php");

    // If the string "index.php" is contained in these results, remove it
    // array_search returns the key of the $needle parameter (or false) if not found
    if (($location = array_search("index.php", $rand_files)) !== false) {
            // If "index.php" was in the results, then delete it from the array using unset()
        unset($rand_files[$location]);
    }

    // Randomly choose 5 of the remaining files:
    foreach (array_rand($rand_files, 5) as $rand_index) {
        $fname = $rand_files[$rand_index];
        echo "<a href='$fname'>$fname</a>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my requirement is something different. I have again updated my question.

Comment: @Joel I've updated my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for replying, As am new to php, i had these doubts.

The script and concept is fine, thank you for the script. But i want to configure a particular folder. How should i do it?

`$directory = 'folder/' ` 


When the final output comes out, i dont want the extensions to be displayed.

Comment: @Joel You need to edit your original question to show some input and output of what you need. For example, what are some of the filenames? What links/text should be created given those file names?

Comment: The code which I've mentioned displays all the files in a particular folder. But i want only any five random files to be displayed. 
1. The file extension should not be displayed
2. I need " " instead of "-" in the file names

Comment: @TajMorton, what if I had multiple php files i want to exclude like: index.php, header.php, sidebar.php . thanks